# Open Set, Closed Set and Bounded Set

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I really tried to understand the concept of open and closed set and boundary, but I did not get it quite well. I have questions about it. First is there anyone who tell me exactly these concepts?

And then I encounter a question about it like this:
$$S = \{(x, y)|x \in [0, 2] , 2x + y < 1\}\text{ where }x \in\mathbb R\text{ and }y \in\mathbb R\text,$$
About the nature of this set, how can I show that it is not bounded? and it is not closed? Is it open or neither open nor closed?

Also, how can I maximize $f(x, y) = x + 2y$ over the set $S$. Is it a problem that this set is not bounded and not closed?

Comment: Can you draw the set $S$?

Comment: I could not. I thought, y < 1 and the set is not bounded. But i couldn't answer the question exactly.

Comment: Can you draw $2x+y=1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you could draw $y=1-2x$ and the below part of the area intersected with the rectangle $[0,2]\times \mathbb{R}$ it's your desired set (kind of infinite trapezium, with left and right borders being part of $S$ and up and down basis being not part of $S$ in turn $S$ is not open nor close). A way to see if a set it's closed it's to check the boundary, it contains the boundary or not? In this case it's just enough to check at $(0,1)$, this point it's on the boundary because for any small ball you get values on $S$ and outside $S$ i.e., for $x=0$ values such that $y<1$ and $y\geq 1$, and evidently $(0,1)\notin S$, so $S$ couldn't be closed. Try at the point $(0,0)$ and check that is on the boundary and it's on $S$ so $S$ can't be open.

Also, since $y$ is not bounded as the only condition it's $y<1-2x$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}$ we see that $-\infty<y<1$ therefore $S$ is not bounded.

The function $f(x,y)=x+2y$ has a local max, which is $(0,1)$ but is not on $S$ so $f$ couldn't be optimized on $S$.

Comment: Ok, now get it. thank you so much. In this case,  function of f(x,y)=x+2y have not maximize point on S, because of S is not closed. Am i right?

Comment: check at this https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3C1-2x+and+0%3C%3D+x%3C%3D+2

Comment: Actually you could maximize the function $x+2y$ and see that locally the max it's $(0,1)\notin S$  look https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+x%2B2y+on+y%3C1-2x+and+0%3C%3D+x%3C%3D+2

Comment: Got it thank you so much again.

Comment: @AhmetErkamSaraç consider accept it the answer if was helpful